# Grab Dynamic HTML Tag from page source

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to create a bot that can automate a task by pulling a report from a website. I'll preface by saying that I'm not savvy with HTML or Javascript either so forgive me if I use incorrect terminology. Here's the issue:

I write code in Python to have the bot open the page and then click a button on the page. Beforehand I inspect the page to get the HTML code for the button that needs to be clicked and insert that into my Python code. Say for example this it the HTML:

```
<div class = "export-data-button-group bar", id = "xyz-123zyx">
<div class = "export-data-button 347-trigger", tabindex = "0", type = "button">
<svg aria-hidden = "true" class = "export-button__icon">
```

However, once the bot opens the page itself, the code for the button changes. Here's a visual to explain:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_driver_binary = r"C:\users\user\folder\folder\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options = options)
driver.get(url)
drop_down = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "export data button 347")
drop_down.click()
```

In the 5th line of code, once the bot opens the page, then button label will change from "export data button 347" to something like "random data button 922".

How can I solve for this?

I've researched how to solve for this issue but don't seem to have any luck on finding answers for grabbing a changing piece of html code.

Comment: Can you share some more part of the HTML mark-up? The HTML before and after that button?

Comment: Hey Shawn, I've added the before and after to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using XPATH locator strategy, something like below:

```
drop_down = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='xyz-123zyx']//div")
```

Or this:

```
drop_down = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='xyz-123zyx']//div)[1]")
```

**NOTE:** Assumption is that `id` attribute's value `xyz-123zyx` doesn't change. If this value also is dynamic then above XPath locator won't work.

Comment: Thank you! What if the ID attribute does change, then what's the fix? A thought I had was to have the bot open the page, then use scrape all the html tags into a list, then use a regex to find the tag that is the closest match but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Identify something which won't change, based on it, construct your XPATH expression.